# Trouble Understanding the ESRI API

Tags: javascript, api, gis, esri

I am new to the ESRI Javascript API.  I do not understand what needs to go on the attr on the line with new graphic.

```
var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geoPoint, symbol, attr, infoTemplate);
```

This is the last piece of the many samples codes i have tied together.  Will someone please suggest a solution.  Thank you for your help.  Below is the entire function.  Let me know if you need the entire script.

```
function onGeocodesuccess(results)
{
console.log(results);

    var geoPoint = new esri.geometry.Point(results.utm_x, results.utm_y, map.spatialReference);
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 15, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0,0,255]), 2), new dojo.Color([0,0,255]));
    var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("Attributes", "${*}");
    var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geoPoint, symbol, attr, infoTemplate);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
    map.infoWindow.setTitle(graphic.getTitle());
    map.infoWindow.setContent(graphic.getContent());
    var screenPnt = map.toScreen(geoPoint);
    map.infoWindow.show(screenPnt,map.getInfoWindowAnchor(screenPnt));


}
```

Comment: A [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net) is always useful.

Comment: All i have working is the base map.  I will add the rest of the file so you can copy it to an html file of your own.  Fiddle wasnt liking the way it got broke up and i dont have this hosted anywhere. @JaredFarrish

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is required for the "attr" variable as it is optional.  In your example above I would remove the "attr" as it is not defined in the function or needed.

```
var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geoPoint, symbol, attr, infoTemplate);
```

ESRI has descent documentation for the [Graphic Class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphic-amd.html#attributes).

Answer (score 0):

attr is an object with keys of the fields names and values of the field values, it  is generally populated with features returned from the server. When you're creating a new graphic, this is an optional parameter and as mentioned you can leave off this parameter when creating a new graphic, in your case this would be:

```
function onGeocodesuccess(results) {
console.log(results);

var geoPoint = new esri.geometry.Point(results.utm_x, results.utm_y, map.spatialReference);
var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 15, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0,0,255]), 2), new dojo.Color([0,0,255]));
var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("Attributes", "${*}");
var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geoPoint, symbol);
map.graphics.add(graphic);
map.infoWindow.setTitle(graphic.getTitle());
map.infoWindow.setContent(graphic.getContent());
var screenPnt = map.toScreen(geoPoint);
map.infoWindow.show(screenPnt,map.getInfoWindowAnchor(screenPnt));

}
```